# Expression for a bounded function

Tags: functions, regular-expressions

I have a bounded function,

$$
y=
    \begin{cases}
        1 & \text{if $x>1$} \\
        x & \text{if $0\leq x\leq 1$}\\
        0 &\text{if $x < 0$}
    \end{cases}
$$
Does anyone know any simple math function to represent $y$? (not using a piece-wise function)

For example, Heaviside function is a similar approach.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying unit step function is okay to use?

Comment: I doubt it's necessary to use the unit step function.  The absolute value function plus stuff not normally defined piecewise ought to be enough.

Comment: I've added an answer in which the only function used that is normally defined piecewise is the absolute value.

Comment: There may have been an error in my answer, and it was probably too complicated.  Now it says $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{|x|+x}{2} - \frac{(x-1)+|x-1|}{2}$.  That should do it. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3):

Let $H$ denote the unit step function.

$xH(x)$ is zero when $x$ is negative and equal to $x$ when $x$ is positive. $xH(x-1)$ is zero when $x$ is less than 1 and equal to $x$ otherwise. If I'm not mistaken, $$xH(x) - (x-1)H(x-1)$$ is the function you want.

Answer (score 3):

$$
f(x) = \frac{|x|+x}{2} - \frac{(x-1)+|x-1|}{2}.
$$

(This can be simplified a bit.)

Comment: I've just done a small emendation that makes this simpler and possibly corrects it.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=x[x>0] + (1-x)[x>1]$$
Where $[x>0]$ denotes the [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), equalling $1$ if the expression is true, and $0$ otherwise.  You can also use an indicator function  if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice notation for this: $y=(x\wedge 1)\vee 0$.

Note: this is just shorthand for $y=\max (\min(x,1),0)$.

Answer (score -1):

[$$
\int \rm rect\left( x- \frac12\right)\rm dx,
$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eaaaraugnp7)
but be careful when choosing $\rm{const}$...

Comment: What is "rect"?

Comment: @MPW the [$\rm rect$angular function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function)...